# I need correct time from `1609891200000` without using Moment

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, moment-timezone

```
var now = moment(1609891200000, "x").format('MMM DD h:mm A');
var x = new Date(1609891200000);
console.log(now); // Prints Jan 06 12:00 AM
console.log(x.toLocaleTimeString()); // Prints 05:30:00
```

I don't know why I keep getting 5:30 as time. I need a way to get the correct time i.e `12:00 AM` without the use of Moment.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide a code of time zone,
If there is no code, then it will provide by default

```
var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 12, 3, 0, 0));

// toLocaleTimeString() without arguments depends on the implementation,
// the default locale, and the default time zone
console.log(date.toLocaleTimeString());
// → "7:00:00 PM" if run in en-US locale with time zone America/Los_Angeles
```

Instead, you can use

```
var x = new Date(1609891200000);
x.toGMTString() // "Wed, 06 Jan 2021 00:00:00 GMT"
x.toUTCString() // "Wed, 06 Jan 2021 00:00:00 GMT"
x.toISOString() // "2021-01-06T00:00:00.000Z"
```

Comment: Also you can use next options: 
`new Date(1609891200000).toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour12: true, hour: '2-digit', timeZone: 'UTC', timeZoneName: 'short', minute: '2-digit' })` // "12:00 AM UTC"